# WPF Datagrid not displaying itemSource data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, list, datagrid

I am passing a list as a itemsource  of datagrid but datagrid not showing any data in interface. Help me I am new to wpf.I tried many times i didnt get my output results properly.

```
public partial class Home : Window
{
    List<Member> members = new List<Member>();
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();

        memberGrid.ItemsSource = members;
    }
    void LoadData()
    {
        Member member = new Member()
        {
            id = 1,name="raj",dob="monday",mobileno="27487228"
        };
        members.Add(member);
    }
}
public class Member
{
    public  int id;
    public   string name;
    public  string dob;
    public string mobileno;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hello please set the properties to getter setter
problem in Class

DataGrid generates columns automatically only for properties, because each column creates a binding and WPF bindings require properties. DisplayTable class declares fields.

instead of

public  int id;

try this

```
public class Member
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string mobileno { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is not the full answer addressing the problem. Since he is adding items to the source collection _after_ assigning it to the `ItemsSource`, the collection `members` must be a `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`. Or the assignment must happen _after_ the `Member` items were added to the `members` collection. This answer doesn't fix the code, it's only a part of the solution. Could you please add this to your answer?

Comment: yes, but problem in class properties..this class can be taken in Observable Collection. I am not saying to not use the  Observable Collection that way i am saying that -@BionicCode

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, the missing properties are a problem. But even when fixing this by adding properties to `Member` the `DataGrid` will still be empty, because he's adding items to the source collection _AFTER_  it was assigned to `ItemsSource`. The `DataGrid`can't update to reflect the added items.